# Selecting first records of a type in a given period

Tags: mysql, select

I have a database table that stores user comments:

```
comments(id, user_id, created_at)
```

From that table, I want to get the number of users that have commented for the first time in the past 7 days.

---

Here's what I have so far:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `user_id`) 
FROM `comments` 
WHERE `created_at` BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND NOW()
```

This would give the number of users that have commented, but it would not take into consideration whether these comments are first for their users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id)
FROM comments AS c1
WHERE c1.created_at BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND NOW()
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM comments AS c2 
                WHERE c2.user_id = c1.user_id AND c2.created_at < c1.created_at)
```

The `NOT EXISTS` clause checks whether the same user_id has a record with an earlier created_at time. If so, it means this is not the first time they are commenting, and thus we should discount this record.

I have kept `DISTINCT user_id` because it is possible two comments are created at the same time. You could also try the following instead, which only gets the *very first* record for each user, so you can do away with the DISTINCT, but I don't know which would be more optimal:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM comments AS c1
WHERE c1.created_at BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND NOW()
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM comments AS c2 
                WHERE c2.user_id = c1.user_id 
                AND (c2.created_at < c1.created_at 
                    OR (c2.created_at = c1.created_at AND c2.id < c1.id)))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `user_id`) 
FROM comments c1
WHERE created_at BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND NOW()
AND NOT EXISTS 
   (SELECT NULL 
   FROM comments c2 
   where c1.user_id = c2.user_id
   AND c2.create_at < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY));
```

Comment: +1 for the SELECT NULL. The check for `NOT EXISTS` should be faster.

Comment: I let this answer (as it is semantically correct), but suggest you to choose lc.'s one (which avoid to repeat the "time" clause, which makes query easier to maintain)